# Check in bash if directory does not exist when managed by update-alternatives

Tags: bash, debian, apt

I have a path that is managed by update-alternatives.  It seems this is confusing bash.

The following if should not print yes.  But it does because bash thinks the directory does not exist - when in fact it does.  This is all done as root, and I've tried the single bracket versions.

```
RUBY_ROOT=/usr/bin/ruby
CHK_DIR_PATH=`readlink -f "${RUBY_ROOT}"`
if [[ ! -d "${CHK_DIR_PATH}" ]] ; then echo yes; fi
```

The path does exist:

```
ls -la ${CHK_DIR_PATH}
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6993617 2011-06-21 15:37 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.2-p180
```

Is there an alternative way to check if a directory does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path exists, but it's not a directory; according to your `ls -l`, it's a *file*.  So `test -d` correctly returns false, whereas `test -e` and `test -f` would return true.  I suspect you have something installed incorrectly.

Comment: Yes it was and is a file,  Too tired to tell the files from the folders :)